# Copying an array from a jQuery ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to copy a JSON array in this Javascript function:

```
var test = new array();
function showUser(user, pass, remember)
{
    $.getJSON("login.php", { username : user, password : pass, check : remember }, function(data){  
    for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        alert(data[i]);
        test[i] = data[i];
    }
    });
    alert(test[0]);
}
```

Here is the PHP file it links to;

```
<?php
$arr = array("test1", "test2", "test3");

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

The problem is that I need to run through the function twice so that my test array contains something, otherwise it remains undefined. How do I fix this?

Comment: Oh your code formatting is so misleading... the `for` statement is inside the callback function, but the last `alert()` call isn't... That `alert()` is invoked *before* the JSON callback, so `undefined` is the expected value.

Comment: Can you provide more context?  Where is showUser being called from?

Comment: I'm sorry that the formatting is misleading, I've been trying to get this working for a while and it got somewhat nasty along the process. showUser is being called by a button.

Answer (score 3):

```
var test = new array();
function showUser(user, pass, remember)
{
    $.getJSON("login.php", { username : user, password : pass, check : remember }, function(data){  
        for (i in data)
        {
            test[i] = data[i];
        }
        alert(test[0]);
    });
}
```

As Šime Vidas stated, your alert was outside the callback function so it was being called before the data was returned via your AJAX call. That is why the second click on your button alerted what you expected, because it existed after the callback function ran.

Although, rather than loop through the `data` variable, why not just set `test` to the value of `data`:

```
test = data;
```

Comment: So there is no way to put the data into a variable in a scope outside the AJAX call? That's why the alert was outside the call. I'm trying to put the data array inside the test array to use it outside. As for why I was looping, doing what you suggested didn't give me the result I wanted.

Comment: Your `test` variable is global, so it can be accessed anywhere, but AJAX calls are asynchronous which means they allow other code to run while the AJAX call is waiting on a response. So you CAN access the data outside the callback function, however you have to wait for the callback function to run before the data will be available. I recommend using a development tool such as Firebug which will allow you to see in real-time the requests being sent.

Comment: So how would I access the data outside the callback? I'm not sure I understand. I can access what the data contains within the callback, so why can't I just pass it on to my test array?

Comment: `test` is global (meaning any JavaScript code ran can access it), but it is an empty array until the callback function runs, which is where you assign it a value. A good example that you can setup yourself is to make a button that alerts the contents of `test` that is separate from the button that runs the `showUser()` function. That way you can see that with one button/function you can assign a value to `test` and with another button/function you can read that value.

Comment: I think I somewhat get what you mean, looking at firebug. However, how do I make sure that the AJAX call completes before I run the rest of the code in showUser?

Comment: Normally you would just put the rest of the code inside the callback function. Like I did in my answer. Basically, anything you want to do with the response from your AJAX call, should be placed in the callback function for that AJAX call.

Comment: You're welcome, this concept can be tricky to wrap your mind around but understanding when the data becomes available should help you down the path.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to copy an array is with `slice`:

```
test = data.slice(0);
```

Comment: Just `data.slice()` works too (since `ToInteger( undefined )` evaluates to `0`).